# GPU Manual Mipmap Generation [OpenGL 2.x]

Tags: opengl, gpu, shader, mipmaps

i want use a specific customized algorithm to generate mipmaps for some renderable textures (R16F & RGBA16F).

All needed textures' mipmaps are pre-enabled by using glGenerateMipmapEXT().

The biggest problem so far is to render into 1+ mipmap levels.
**More precisely,
this works like a charm:**

```
...
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, target, texType, texId, 0 );
checkFBOStatus();
...
render();
```

**But this gives me a GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT_EXT when checking fbo status**

```
...
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT( GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, target, texType, texId, 1 );
checkFBOStatus();
...
render();
```

***All the difference in code is the lod level parameter for attaching a texture onto the FBO.***

after lots of feverish head-scratching, i still cant get it work.
So, any answer is greatly appreciated.

[NOTE: target platform is OpenGL 2.x with FBO extension]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem SOLVED

---

The reason of FBO incomplete is due to texture consistence.
When using glGenerateMipmapEXT/glGenerateMipmap, u must make sure your texture's base level contains **VALID DATA**; otherwise, that call fails without any error notification.

There're two possible solutions for your referrence:

1. Use TexImage or TexSubImage to
   fillup your renderable texture
   before glGenerateMipmap
2. Attach the renderable texture to a
   dummy FBO before glGenerateMipmap

**Either way works (tested on GF8,GF9)
Not tested on ATI cards.**

That'd be great if anyone can test it out on ATI GPUs.

*PS. Pls let me know if u have problem using these solutions.*

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I'm having the same problem on ATI Radeon 9800. 
But I made a call with gltexImage2D.

Render to the first level is possible but not the others. Maybe I should try the dummy FBO method.

Comment: I'm look forward to see your result of dummy FBO experiment.

Comment: Actually I gave up with this and used hardware mipmap for these cards. 
Some gotchas about ATI GPU, epspecially the older R300 series (tested on Radeon 9700 to x700) :
 can't render to NPOT texture
| can't use texture2DLod in the fragment shader
| must stick to #version 110 to use them
| can't have const arrays of matrices
| can't have dynamic indices in an array
| cannot switch-case either (x700)
| must call glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_xD) when binding textures or your GLSL samplers will return black